# Matplotlib Plot points on an existing line, only by knowing x values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have 2 dataframes:

'stock' is a dataframe with columns Date and Price.
'events' is a dataframe with columns Date and Text.

My goal is to produce a graph of the stock prices and on the line place dots where the events occur. However, I do not know how to do 'y' value for the events dataframe as I want it to be where it is on the stock dataframe.

I am able to plot the first dataframe fine with:

```
plt.plot('Date', 'Price', data=stock)
```

And I try to plot the event dots with:

```
plt.scatter('created_at', ???, data=events)
```

However, it is the ??? that I don't know how to set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Date` and `created_at` are `datetime`:

```py
stock = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01','2021-04-01','2021-05-01'],'Price':[1,5,3,4,10]})
events = pd.DataFrame({'created_at':['2021-02-01','2021-03-01'],'description':['a','b']})

stock.Date = pd.to_datetime(stock.Date)
events.created_at = pd.to_datetime(events.created_at)
```

Filter `stock` by `events.created_at` (or merge) and plot them onto the same `ax` :

```py
stock_events = stock[stock.Date.isin(events.created_at)]

# or merge on the date columns
# stock_events = stock.merge(events, left_on='Date', right_on='created_at')

ax = stock.plot(x='Date', y='Price')
stock_events.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='Date', y='Price', label='Event', c='r', s=50)
```

[image: stock events]